# AWS AMI -Filter Latest Version

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Maybe I am trying to use AWS EC2 incorrectly, please help me out. I would like to make a base ami via a user data script, this is no problem, it works. However, the next step is to make an image, however since the object is untagged its kind of a pain to filter for it, I can add criteria for region, vpc, security group and state, this would find the object and I could build the image.

However I do not want to overwrite the existing image, so ideally i need to tag this with a name and version, no problem. But then I need the child images to find that image, and i would like to find via name and version, but dynamically, i.e. latest. In docker it is pretty straight forward as long as the container is tagged, to use latest the version can be omitted and it will auto pull the latest. Is there a similar technique here? What do you guys use? Am I possibly using this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

*Note: although this is for is tagging an instance, it can easily be modified to work with images.*

*Note: I am not a powershell power user, so if you see a glaring inefficiency, please let me know.*

I use Jenkins to build the machine, as such it has environment variables that I use for the tagging, however it calls a powershell script that has this signature, so you could manually call or call it via another script:

```
param(
    ...
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Tag_Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Tag_Version
)
```

Inside of this script, I set the instance tags like so:

```
#Get metadata from ec2 service
$identityDocument = (Invoke-WebRequest http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document/).Content | ConvertFrom-Json

$tags = @( 
    @{Key = "Name"; Value = $Tag_Name},
    @{Key = "Version"; Value = $Tag_Version}
)

New-EC2Tag -Resource $identityDocument.instanceId -Tag $tags
```

In another script, I can query by name, find all instances, parse the result into a hash table of [InstanceId, Version], sort by Version and get the top one.

```
$instanceName = "hello-world"
$instances = GetHashTableOfFilteredInstances $instanceName
$instanceId = GetNewestInstance($instances)

Write-Host 'Information for ' $instanceName
Write-Host '================='
Write-Host 'The newest instance is ' $instanceId
Write-Host '================='

function GetHashTableOfFilteredInstances($tagName){
    $instances = Get-EC2Instance -Filter @( `
      @{name='tag:Name'; values=$tagName};`
    ) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty instances

    $actInstances= @{}

    foreach($instance in $instances){
       foreach($tag in $instance.Tag){
          if ($tag.Key -ne "Version") {
             Continue;
          }

          $actInstances.Add($tag.Value, $instance.InstanceId)
       }
    }

    return $actInstances
 }

 function GetNewestInstance($instances){
     return ($instances.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Key -descending)[0].Value
 }
```

Comment: Of course, I can filter by created time like so: $ami = Get-EC2Image -Region $Region -Owner self | Where-Object {$_.Name.StartsWith("windows-iis-ami")} | `
            Sort-Object -Property CreationDate -Descending | `
            Select-Object -First 1 | `
            Select -ExpandProperty ImageId